# How to select only numbers from a text field

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

How can I pull only the number from a field and put that value into its own field?

For example, if a field1 contains a value of "Name(1234U)".

I need an SQL or VBA way to scan that field and pull the number out. So field2 will equal "1234".

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks RedAces, although that works in mySQL, I need SQL or VBA for MS Access 2007. The values can be different in the field, but the numbers will always be together.  So it could be default(4321U) or something(7263A)

Comment: Who ever is voting to close, please note that SQL is a generic term and Access SQL is not the same as MySQL or SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that this or a variation may suit:

```
 SELECT t.Field1, Mid([Field1],InStr([field1],"(")+1,4) AS Stripped
 FROM TheTable As t
```

For example:

```
 UPDATE TheTable AS t SET [field2] = Mid([Field1],InStr([field1],"(")+1,4);
```

EDIT re comment

If the field ends `u)`, that is, alpha bracket, you can say:

```
 UPDATE TheTable AS t SET [field2] =
 Mid([Field1],InStr([field1],"(")+1,Len(Mid([Field1],InStr([field1],"(")))-3)
```

Comment: How could I adjust this to be dynamic and allow a field to have 3 numbers and maybe 5 numbers together?

Comment: For example, a field may hold "name(12345U)"

Comment: Thats the ticket! ;) Thank you @Remou

Answer (score 2):

The following VBA function might do the trick:

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function RegexReplaceAll( _
        OriginalText As Variant, _
        Pattern As String, _
        ReplaceWith As String) As Variant
    Dim rtn As Variant
    Dim objRegExp As Object  ' RegExp

    rtn = Null
    If Not IsNull(OriginalText) Then
        Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")  ' New RegExp
        objRegExp.Pattern = Pattern
        objRegExp.Global = True
        rtn = objRegExp.Replace(OriginalText, ReplaceWith)
        Set objRegExp = Nothing
    End If
    RegexReplaceAll = rtn
End Function
```

Example using the regular expression pattern

```
[^0-9]+
```

which matches one or more non-digit characters

```
RegexReplaceAll("Name(1234U)","[^0-9]+","")
```

returns

```
1234
```

edit:

To use this in a query *run from within the Access application itself*, try something like

```sql
SELECT Field1, RegexReplaceAll(Field1,"[^0-9]+","") AS JustNumbers
FROM Table1;
```

Comment: What happens if 'something' is for example, 'User1'?

Comment: @Remou `RegexReplaceAll("User1","[^0-9]+","")` returns `1`, as expected.

Comment: I did not express that well `User1(1234U)`

Comment: How can I run that code within vba but reference a field name? Like ?RegexReplaceAll(table.field,"[^0-9]+","")

Comment: @Remou Like the title says, `RegexReplaceAll("User1(1234U)","[^0-9]+","")` returns just the numbers: `11234`

Comment: Im getting the error "Undefined function 'RegexReplaceAll' in expression...am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Remou That is ok for my solution. But i understand you concept

Comment: @AntonHughes Did you paste the VBA code into a regular VBA Module (not a Class Module for a form/report)?

Comment: @Remou Put in a Change Request and when there's budget available we'll take a look at it. ;)

Comment: @GordThompson Hi, I have pasted that function into a regular module, import the library 'Microsoft VBSript Regular Expressions 5.5' and it still mentions that the function 'regexreplaceall' is still undefined! Any ideas?

Comment: @AntonHughes I have updated the code in my answer. You can also download a working example [here](http://wikisend.com/download/955246/regexTest.zip).

Answer (score 0):

Create a VBA function, call it as a field in your query and pass it the original field (like `select GetNumerals(field1) from table...`).  The VBA function will loop through each letter in the field and return only the numeric values.  It could look something like this:

```
Public Function GetNumerals(str As String) As String

Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To Len(str)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(str, i, 1)) Then
            GetNumerals = GetNumerals & Mid(str, i, 1)
        End If
    Next i

End Function
```