# How to substring a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, database

For example:

```
CE-0392(Ne)
CEU-29221(PR)
```

Expected result:

```
0392
29221
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select only numbers from a text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21286804/how-to-select-only-numbers-from-a-text-field)

Comment: @Sal00m That question isn't about MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING("CE-0392(Ne)", 4,4) AS ExtractString;
SELECT SUBSTRING("CEU-29221(PR)", 5,5) AS ExtractString;
```

But you could use a mix of [LEFT](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-left-function.php) and [LOCATE](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-locate-function.php) or even [SUBSTRING_INDEX](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php) if you characters are fixed, for instance, always between `-` and `(`.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX("CE-0392(Ne)", '-', -1),'(', 1) AS ExtractString;
```

Comment: thanks, I just want to display characters between - and (

Comment: I could not tell when you first described it. I have now edited the answer.

Comment: Neil, did that help? Perhaps you could provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to have the correct answer 'cause your question is not clear, please add more details (are `CE-0392(Ne)` and `CEU-29221(PR)` extracted from a query ? If yes which one ? )
You can use MySQL String function like, like:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('CE-0392(Ne)','(',1);
```

Please visit http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php for further reference.